# Swift - How to cast Any to Array \ Dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, swift4

I'm trying to parse a json which has an array with Strings, Ints and Arrays

So I'm to iterate on the json {["item1", 2, ["subItem1", "subitem2"] ]}  members in the array:

```
func parse(json : [Any])
for item in json{
    if let arr = item as? Array { //
         //do stuff for array
    } 
}
```

but I'm getting this compile error:

> Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred in cast to
>   'Array<_>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional bind `item` to the different types

```
for item in json {
    if let stringItem = item as? String {
         //do stuff for String
    } else if let intItem = item as? Int {
        //do stuff for Int
    } else if let arrayItem = item as? [String] {
       //do stuff for Array
    } else {
       // it's something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll add my 2 cents here i guess as i was typing this same answer. You can also call the `parse` method recursively if you want to handle the subarray in the same way.

Comment: I would prefer a switch for that `switch item {
        case let arr as [String]:
            print(arr)
        default:
            break
        }`

Answer (score 1):

You receive the error is because in Swift, `Array` is a generic container that holds values of a specific type. So you can have an `Array<Int>` that holds integers, or an Array that holds strings. But you can’t have just an Array. The type of the thing the array contains is the generic parameter, and Swift is complaining because it can’t figure out what that type should be. Sometimes it can infer that type from the context of the code around it, but not always, as in this case.

```
func parse(json : [Any])
for item in json{
    if let arr = item as? Array<Any> { //
         //do stuff for array
    } 
}
```

Instead of writing `Array<Any>`, you can write the shorter form, `[Any]`.

You can also solve the problem by using `NSArray`, as you’ve found. Unlike `Array`, `NSArray` doesn’t use generics, since it originates in Objective-C which has a different approach to Swift. Instead, `NSArray` holds only one kind of thing, an `AnyObject`. This is is a reference that can point to instances of any class.

Comment: Additionally the shorthand form for working with Dictionaries would be `[AnyHashable: Any]`.

Comment: yes that's true, or [String: Any] if we know that the keys will be strings